# Pointer type is hidden or not shown on LLVM function type

Tags: llvm

I have a piece of codes which constructs IR within a function like below.

```
SmallVector<Type*, 24> argTypes;
Type *t_1xi32 = Type::getInt32Ty(TheContext);
Type *t_2xi32 = FixedVectorType::get(t_1xi32, 2); t_2xi32->dump();
Type *ptrType = t_2xi32->getPointerTo(0); ptrType->dump();
argTypes.push_back(ptrType);
FunctionType *funcType = FunctionType::get(TheBuilder.getInt32Ty(), argTypes, false);
Function *func = Function::Create(funcType, Function::ExternalLinkage, "test0", TheModule);
BasicBlock *entryBB = BasicBlock::Create(TheContext, "entry", func);
TheBuilder.SetInsertPoint(entryBB);
TheBuilder.CreateGEP(TheBuilder.getInt32Ty(), func->getArg(0), TheBuilder.getInt32(0));
TheBuilder.CreateRet(TheBuilder.getInt32(0));
```

But when I compile and dump the function.

```
define i32 @test0(ptr %0) {
entry:
  %1 = getelementptr i32, ptr %0, i32 0
  %2 = getelementptr i32, ptr %0, i32 1
  ret i32 0
}
```

It confuses me because I would expect something like this

```
%1 = getelementptr i32, <2 x i32>* %0, i32 0
```

Comment: Recent versions of LLVM use an opaque pointer type. You have read a tutorial for an older version.

Comment: Ah, I see. Not only a tutorial, but also some projects I google in the Internet still generate non-opaque pointer which gives me the impression that it is supposed to see type. Somehow it is intuitive for non-opaque. Anyway, thank you very much for letting me know it is called opaque pointer.